# Multiple undefined reference errors when linking freeglut and codelite (minGW32 c++)

Tags: c++, windows, freeglut, codelite

While trying to install (if that's the right word) opengl onto my codelite IDE to create c++ opengl programs, I have run into multiple undefined reference errors in the freeglut_std.h file as well as well known functions like glutMainLoop() are also "undefined".

So I have actually found the function definitions in the freeglut_std.h file and I have tried messing with the header file to make sure that there is no false conditions causing my definitions not to be created. (like making #if true ..... #endif (so that the code will for sure run)). I have experience in C but have never linked files like this before. Going through several webpages like: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/HowTo_OpenGL_C.html , https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/ I linked my files. (Also note, that this question has been asked before however most posts had different solutions that didn't work for me)

So here is how codelite is compling my files (with not erroneous code) :

```
C:/mingw-w64/i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/admin/Documents/codelite/workspaces/c_plus_plus/cpp_openGL/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -I"C:\mingw-w64\i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\mingw32\include"  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
C:/mingw-w64/i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/cpp_openGL @"cpp_openGL.txt" -L.   -m32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread -L"C:\mingw-w64\i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\mingw32\lib" -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglu32
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/admin/Documents/codelite/workspaces/c_plus_plus/cpp_openGL'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

However for something like this (actual test code):

```
/*
 * GL01Hello.cpp: Test OpenGL C/C++ Setup
 */

#include <windows.h>  // For MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, includes glu.h and gl.h

/* Handler for window-repaint event. Call back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window needs to be re-painted. */
void display() {
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer

   // Draw a Red 1x1 Square centered at origin
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
      glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
      glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
      glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();  // Render now
}

/* Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main()  */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
   glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
   glutInitWindowSize(320, 320);   // Set the window's initial width & height
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
   glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
   glutMainLoop();          // Enter the infinitely event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':
C:/mingw-w64/i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:623: undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':
C:/mingw-w64/i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:625: undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':
C:/mingw-w64/i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0/mingw32/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:627: undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/admin/Documents/codelite/workspaces/c_plus_plus/cpp_openGL/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitWindowSize@8'
C:/Users/admin/Documents/codelite/workspaces/c_plus_plus/cpp_openGL/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `_imp__glutInitWindowPosition@8'
C:/Users/admin/Documents/codelite/workspaces/c_plus_plus/cpp_openGL/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `_imp__glutDisplayFunc@4'
C:/Users/admin/Documents/codelite/workspaces/c_plus_plus/cpp_openGL/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `_imp__glutMainLoop@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
====7 errors, 0 warnings====
```

The file that it is complain about is freeglut_std.h, the following is copied from the file:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK) && !defined(__WATCOMC__)
FGAPI void FGAPIENTRY __glutInitWithExit(int *argcp, char **argv, void (__cdecl *exitfunc)(int));
FGAPI int FGAPIENTRY __glutCreateWindowWithExit(const char *title, void (__cdecl *exitfunc)(int));
FGAPI int FGAPIENTRY __glutCreateMenuWithExit(void (* func)(int), void (__cdecl *exitfunc)(int));
#ifndef FREEGLUT_BUILDING_LIB
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define FGUNUSED __attribute__((unused))
#else
#define FGUNUSED
#endif
static void FGAPIENTRY FGUNUSED glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK(int *argcp, char **argv) { __glutInitWithExit(argcp, argv, exit); }//<--has problem with
#define glutInit glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK
static int FGAPIENTRY FGUNUSED glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK(const char *title) { return __glutCreateWindowWithExit(title, exit); }//<--has problem with
#define glutCreateWindow glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK
static int FGAPIENTRY FGUNUSED glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK(void (* func)(int)) { return __glutCreateMenuWithExit(func, exit); } //<--has problem with
#define glutCreateMenu glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK
#endif
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Note that I could get rid the 3-undefined references with:

```
#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK
```

However the remaining errors still exist.

A final note in freeglut_std.h the following lines exist (are these not definitions)

```
FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInit( int* pargc, char** argv );
FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInitWindowPosition( int x, int y );
FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInitWindowSize( int width, int height );
FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInitDisplayMode( unsigned int displayMode );
FGAPI void    FGAPIENTRY glutInitDisplayString( const char* displayMode );
```

And something must be working since it doesn't complain about

```
glutinit(param...)
glutCreateWindow(param...)
```

**UPDATE**
I should let you guys know that I have a freeglut.dll file saved in the same location as my application. However that shouldn't matter because I also tried a static build white I used `-DFREEGLUT_STATIC` in the complier command, and linked `-lfreeglut_static` This had the same result, except the `_imp_` part of the error was gone.

So in short I am bamboozled here, Any help is always greatly appreciated.
(p.s. please spare me mods).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28787243/6401656

Comment: `undefined reference to _imp___` normally means that you included headers specifying the functions will be in a DLL/shared object, but you linked against a normal library.  I see from the rest of freeglut_std.h that it does actually offer the option to use either DLL or static libraries, maybe you used the DLL option.  You could try adding `-DFREEGLUT_STATIC` to the compilation command and doing a full rebuild;  or try linking against DLL import libraries instead of against static libraries

Comment: Should have mentioned that I tried this, I will update the question.